# A subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(3,q)$ of order $q^2(q-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a prime power. Consider the multiplicative group $\textrm{GL}(3,q)$ of the $3 \times 3$ matrixes with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q$ which are invertible. The matrixes
$$
M_{a,b,c} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a  & 0  & 0  \\
 b &  1 & 0  \\
 c &  0 &  1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_q$, $a \neq 0$, form a subgroup $G$ of $\textrm{GL}(3,q)$. My objective is to represent this group $G$ as a known finite group. Note that $G$ has order $q^2(q-1)$. I studied the order of its elements and I found that $G$ has a normal elementary abelian $p$-subgroup $N$ of order $q^2$.
$$
N = \{ M_{1,b,c} \ | \ b,c \in \mathbb{F}_q \}.
$$
Any help to represent the group $G$ as a known finite group would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M\cong(\mathbb{F}_q\oplus\mathbb{F}_q, +)\rtimes\mathbb{F}_q^\times$, where $a\in\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ acts on $\mathbb{F}_q\oplus\mathbb{F}_q$ by vector space scalar multiplication by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: Your $M$ is the group $G$, ok?!

Comment: It was really what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that all your matrices differ from the identity matrix only in the first column: So one can describe this as those non-singular transformations fixing the vectors $e_2$ and $e_3$. This means, $e_1$ should not go to a span of $e_2$ and $e_3$.

So the vector to which $e_1$ is sent, describes an element of the group  completely: This is what Alex Fok's answer contains.